# JMS Serializer: How to set auto_increment value in serialize

Tags: php, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have a class which I want to serialize into a xml-object.
My class has an "id" value and I need to set this. So the first has id=1, the second id=2 etc...
Is it possible to set something in my Class that there is an auto_increment for each generatetd class?
THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

This would generally come from persisting and flushing the entity (assuming you are using doctrine).